# How can I go about creating this design with Java's Swing GUI tools?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

This is a mock up for what I have in mind as a layout for my project:

[image]

[image]

The way I tried to accomplish this is:

I set the entire frame to a border layout and then cut it horizontally with two panels, we'll call them north and south panels. The south panel is Panel 3 from the first picture.

I set the north panel to a border layout as well and cut it vertically with two panels. These become panel 1 and panel 2 in the first picture. The problem occurs when I try to resize the window. I would like the panels to scale proportionally to eachother so the size ratio's between the panels stay the same. The problem is, instead of resizing, the panels just move away from each other like so:

[image]

Any ideas for creating the desired design? Am I on the right track or is there another swing layout that is better suited to my needs?

Comment: *"we'll call them north and south panels"* How about we remove all ambiguity and see what they're called in a [mre] showing the current behavior? BTW - what is the point of giving extra GUI space to the column of 2 buttons on the right? Are the buttons themselves supposed to become larger?

Comment: One thing I can tell is: each component can have its own Layout settings. You can use (for example) FlowLayout in one of your Panels while your base Frame (or other Panels) keeps using BorderLayout. Each layout models has their characteristics, and you can employ best one for each part to build ideal GUI design in your mind.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hey man. Sure, maybe I can do that next time. And the panel with the two buttons doesn't necessarily need to scale with the other two panels, but I think it will need to at-least scale on one axis or the other to maintain the aesthetic of the whole window.

Comment: @MNEMO Thanks for the tip! I do plan on using different layouts to organize the components of the sub-panels. I just thought it would be a good idea to get the panels themselves scaling properly first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like the panels to scale proportionally to eachother so the size ratio's between the panels stay the same.

Try using a horizontal `BoxLayout`. I believe it will allocate extra space proportionally up to the components maximum size if extra space is available.

Or if that doesn't work you can use a `GridBagLayout`. You can use the `weightx` constraint for each component you add to the panel. This will control how much extra space is given to each component.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working example of each.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll look into those options.

Comment: As a general Swing advice, knowing the `GridBagLayout` and its capabilities gives you the most freedom and flexibility, as literally every imaginable layout possible with Swing can be done with `GridBagLayout`, while the other `LayoutManagers` are more specialized and usually only capable of achieving simple layouts.